# Is there a word to describe a work of art that relies on astronomical conditions?

Tags: terminology

I have two examples in mind. The first is this stunning [Veterans' Memorial](http://twistedsifter.com/2014/11/anthem-arizona-veterans-memorial/), and the second is the more prosaic and common examples of [analemnas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analemma) in art, the one in the movie Castaway, for [example](http://www.solsticecalendar.com/uncategorized/the-analemma-in-castaway/).

Note - I don't mean "analemna"...an analemna is a *single* example of a technique for what I'm talking about. I wouldn't say that the Veterans' Memorial strictly uses an analemna, except to the extent that the projection is a particular point on the analemna. In the absence of a better term, I guess I would settle on "analemnic projection", but Google comes up with zero point zero results for that.

Anyhow, whatever what kind of art this is, I really dig it, so I'd like to know if there's a term for it. Surely some Fine Arts post-doc has come up with one.

Comment: Note: It's an "analemma", not an "analemna".  And Google does have three hits for "analemmatic projection", though they are all clearly from the same source material.

Comment: Another notable example may be the moving shadow on the Temple of Kukulcan in Chichen Itza during the equinox.

Comment: Yes, wfaulk, that's exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: Wfaulk, I think "analemmatic projection art" is the answer...I'm getting other examples of the art on Google now. Go ahead and post it and I'll accept it.

Comment: Boy will Arizona be annoyed when procession of the equinoxes messes up their sculpture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an "analemma", not an "analemna". And Google does have three hits for "analemmatic projection", though they are all clearly from the same source material.